# Can I use YouTube transcript data in my blog? Or do I have to make some changes before any blog post?

Tags: copyright

Can I use YouTube transcript data in my blog? Or do I have to make some changes before any blog post? I am unable to understand what is wrong or what is right. Please explain simply.

Comment: It will help in giving a useful answer if you describe in a bit more detail what kind of thing you are trying to do. I have given a general answer, but it might be improved with more information from you. It will also help if you say in what country this would take place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please state your question in a complete way in the body that readers can understand on its own. This is not Reddit, so you can't just post a question in a title and say "in the title" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

That depends very much on what you mean by "use youtube transcript data". It may also depend on what jurisdiction you are in, in this case what country you are in.

In general, one cannot simply copy the words of a youtube video and use them in one's own blog or other publication without permission. Those words are protected by copyright. Limited quotes may perhaps be made under fair use, or fair dealing or another exception to copyright, but the rules will vary depending on the country. Such quotes must usually be limited in both purpose and extent. See threads on this site tagged [fair-use](/questions/tagged/fair-use) for more details.

The ideas discussed and any information presented in the video are not protected by copyright. Thus if a youtube video reports that Joe Smirt was elected Sheriff of Capsicola, you can mention that fact on a blog. But if the video describes the election as "the most wonderful and surprising upset in over a century, leading to a new day for Capsicola" those words are protected, and you should not copy or closely imitate them, unless in a clear quotation, attributed to the author of the video or to whoever actually said them, if that was another person.

It is generally not enough to make minor changes in the words of the source, such as to replace "surprising" with "astonishing". One must rewrite the information in one's own words.

Comment: Who would be the copyright owner in this case? Would it be YouTube or the creator of the video?

Comment: @The Editor  It would initially be the creator of the video, unless that was done as part of the creator's employment, in which case it would be the employer under US law. But the copyright **could** have been later sold or given away, or left if the owner dies. Best guess is the creator as a place to start looking. Copyright transfers can be registered with the US copyright office, but need not be. Youtube does not normally hold the copyright on the videos that they host.